# How to maintain data for chat window while moving to another page

Tags: html, asp.net, chat

**Summary**:

I have designed a chat window and opening this chat page in an `iframe`.
I want to open this chat window in all the pages of my site.

**Requirement**:

So once the user will start the chat session and if the user is moving from one page to another page then chat window should popup automatically by maintaining the previous chat data.

**What I have done**:

For opening the chat window in another page I am explicitly showing `iframe` but data in losing.

Please provide the possible solution.